# How To get the Last 15 minutes values(sessions) for each row in the table in sql select with SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Log Analyzer table Table for reference]

> I want to get a table of
>
> 1> requestTime  2> NumberOfSessionsInLast15minutes
>
> How to write the query to get a table where the requestTime column
>   will be same and the NumberOfSessions column will be sum of sessions
>   in last 15 minutes
>
> EXAMPLE:
>
> The number of sessions for this one 2012-06-06 00:12:00.0000  should
>   be sum of sessions betwen 2012-06-06 00:12:00.0000 and (2012-06-06
>   00:12:00.0000) - 15 minutes .

Comment: You need to clarify your question, because EVERYONE got it wrong. The SUM of sessions for 15 minutes does not imply to me that there should be 15 rows. Please show sample data and desired results, and label them. Your initial screen shot looked to me like sample data, not desired results. After all, if you were able to derive those results using a query, why would you be here asking how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a subquery to retrieve the number of sessions:

```
select  s1.requesttime
,       (
        select  sum(NumberOfSessions)
        from    sessions s2
        where   dateadd(minute, -15, s1.requesttime) < s2.requesttime
                and s2.requesttime <= s1.requesttime
        ) as TotalNumberOfSessions
from    sessions s1
```

Comment: COUNT(*)? Did you mean SUM? Also did you mean to double-count by using BETWEEN? If you run this query exactly 15 minutes later, you'll have included the same minute twice.

Comment: `and s1.requesttime < s1.requesttime`

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE
  @reportTime   DATETIME
SELECT
  @reportTime = '2012-06-06 00:12'

SELECT
  @reportTime,
  SUM(NumberOfSessions)
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
      requestTime >  DATEADD(minute, -15, @reportTime)
  AND requestTime <= @reportTime
```

Mix and match `>=`, `>`, `<` and `<=` depending on your needs and the exact behaviour of your data.

*(Normally a 15 minute window would be `>= 00:00 AND < 00:15`, but your definition is slightly different from that.)*

If you want it for all records in the source table...

```
SELECT
  base.requestTime,
  SUM(history.NumberOfSessions)
FROM
  yourTable    AS base
INNER JOIN
  yourTable    AS history
    ON  history.requestTime >  DATEADD(minute, -15, base.requestTime)
    AND history.requestTime <= base.requestTime
GROUP BY
  base.requestTime
```

Comment: Thank  you for your reply . This one is giving a true result but the problem is it is not giving it for every minute. 
Example : It starts with 2012-06-05 23:59:00.0000000 ... then ...2012-06-06 00:02:00.0000000 ... then ... 2012-06-06 00:10:00.0000000 .... and so on .....its random ? I want it for every minute ...
Thank you so much once again

Comment: @RishiRanka - It's not random. It gives a result at `2012-06-05 23:59` because that's record in your data. It gives a result at `2012-06-06 00:00` because that's the next record in your data. This is based on **`for each row in the table`** in your question title, as well as **`where the requestTime column will be same`** in the question it self. If the issue is just the *order* of the results, you just need to add `ORDER BY base.requestTime`. If you need completely different results, please could you give an example in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it generically, providing a breakdown of 15-minute periods for a given day:

```
DECLARE @requests TABLE(requestTime DATETIME, NumberOfSessions INT);

INSERT @requests SELECT '20120605 23:59', 2
UNION ALL SELECT '20120606 00:00', 500
UNION ALL SELECT '20120606 00:07', 400
UNION ALL SELECT '20120606 00:17', 300
UNION ALL SELECT '20120606 23:57', 500
UNION ALL SELECT '20120607 00:00', 100;

DECLARE @day SMALLDATETIME; -- this would be a stored procedure parameter
SET @day = '20120606';

;WITH n AS 
(
  SELECT TOP 96 n = DATEADD(MINUTE, 15*
  (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])-1), @day)
  FROM sys.all_columns ORDER BY [object_id]
)
SELECT requestTime = n.n, SumNumberOfSessions = COALESCE(SUM(NumberOfSessions), 0)
FROM n LEFT OUTER JOIN @requests AS r
ON r.requestTime >= n
AND r.requestTime < DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, n)
GROUP BY n.n
ORDER BY requestTime;
```

Results:

```
requestTime                SumNumberOfSessions
-----------------------    -------------------
2012-06-06 00:00:00.000    900
2012-06-06 00:15:00.000    300
2012-06-06 00:30:00.000    0
...
2012-06-06 23:30:00.000    0
2012-06-06 23:45:00.000    500
```

Comment: It is showing me 96 records using the inserts given in the OP query and after using your code. Why? **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/acb2d)**

Comment: @PankajGarg Because there are 96 15-minute time slots in a day? Did you read my opening sentence?

Comment: Did you check the result using my SQL Fiddle? It's showing incorrect result set

Comment: @PankajGarg well for one I think you copied the data wrong (you have all data on June 5th) and again I'll suggest you didn't follow the intent of my answer. It is to provide a generic report for *all* of the 15-minute time slices on a given day, not just the last 15 minutes.

Comment: @PankajGarg anyway how did you get your SQLFiddle to work? It uses a `@table` variable and that yields an error to me.

Comment: @Aaron Thank  you for your reply . This one is giving a true result but the problem is it is not giving it for every minute. 
 I want it for every minute ...
Thank you so much once again

Comment: @Rishi so your screen shot at the beginning of your question represents the end result you want, not the data that's already in the table? Can you please update the question with: How did you get that result? What does the source data actually look like? The fact that three different users got your requirement totally wrong should tell you something about the question you've asked.

Comment: @AaronBertrand : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979835/to-write-a-query-to-display-records-for-last-15-minutes-of-sessions-in-the-log-f